# Integration measure

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral

Consider the field being decomposed into a orthogonal and completed basis:

$\Phi(x) = \sum_n c_n \phi_n(x)$ (or $\Phi(x) = \int dk c_k \phi_k (x)$, if continuous)

The notation:

$\phi_n(x) = <x|\phi_n>$ (or $\phi_k = <k|\phi_n>$, if continuous)

The integration measure can be rewritten as:

$\mathcal{D}\Phi \sim \prod_n dc_n$

What is the proportional prefactor? In some literature, it is written as:

$(\det <n|\phi_n>)^{-1}$

But still, what does that mean? I mean, how one calculate it, or write it in function?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1894/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6530/2451 and links therein.