# Measure of Feynman path integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, path-integral, stochastic-processes

Feynman path integral for non-relativistic case is defined as:
$$\int\mathcal{D}[x(t)]e^{iS/\hbar}$$
where $$\int \mathcal{D[x(t)]}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\Pi_{i=0}^{i=N}\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x_{i}\bigg)$$

In the course and the books, I have encountered while studying path integral the term "**measure**" is introduced without any previous notion. The best intuition I have about measure is, it's like a weight you assign to each term of series you're summing (I only understand Riemann integral so it kinda lean towards the idea of area, just a bit of generalization).

Also while studying a little bit about Brownian motion, I came across Wiener process the integral (propagator) used there is almost identical to Feynman's one, the $i$ is replaced by $-1$ but I couldn't understand much about it because the discussion was based on central limit theorem and Lebesgue measure. But the headache-causing thing I remember is while Wiener integrals are convergent Feynman integrals are not (the explanation I came across about it is that it's because of the oscillatory behaviour of the factor, $e^{iS/\hbar}$. The integrals are conditionally convergent, while in the case of Wiener we have decreasing function $e^{-S}$ and that's the reason why we go for $-i\epsilon$ prescription).

As you may have noticed in the above explanation the exponential factor is tugged together with the $\mathcal{D}$ factor to compare with the [Wiener integrals](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Wiener_integral). So is the measure $M$, equals to $\color{red}{\mathcal{D}[x(t)]e^{iS/\hbar}}$ and Feynman integrals are of form $\int M f(x(t))$? People also say that there are Feynman path integrals which don't use Wiener measure but I have never seen them. Do they exist in literature?

When the books make transition from one particle QM to QFT, the authors simply state that propagator is given by
$$\int\mathcal{D}[\phi(x)]e^{iS/\hbar}$$
with no definition of $\mathcal{D}[\phi(x)]$.

I have heard that $\mathcal{D}[\phi(x)]$ can be defined in terms of $a$, $a^{\dagger}$ (annihilation and creation operator) and this has been done by Ludvig Faddeev but couldn't find it.

Comment: In my QFT course, this was explicitly acknowledged as an area of active research: finding out what exactly we mean by "measure", in a rigorous mathematical sense, is something that appears to be a work in progress. I could be wrong, but that was my impression.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1894/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6530/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27665/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

The results in this answer are taken directly from Blank, Exner and Havlíček: Hilbert space operators in quantum physics. Look there for more details.

At least in non-relativistic QM, the path integral is derived/defined using the limiting procedure of “taking finer and finer time-slicing” of the path. The precise formula for a system of $M$ particles is:

\begin{align}
&U(t) \, \psi(x) \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \; \prod_{k=1}^M \; \Big( \frac{m_k \, N}{2\pi\mathrm{i} \, t} \Big)^{N/2} \hspace{-0.2em} \lim_{j_1, ... j_N \to \infty} \; \int_{B_{j_1}\!\times...\times B_{j_N}} \hspace{-3em} \exp(\mathrm{i} \, S(x_1, ...x_N)) \; \psi(x_1) \; \mathrm{d}x_1 \, ... \, \mathrm{d}x_{N-1} \\
&=: \int\exp(\mathrm{i} \, S[x]) \; \mathcal{D}x \,
\end{align}
where $S[x]$ is the classical action over the path $x$ and $S(x_1,...x_N) := S[\gamma]$ is the same action taken over a polygonal line $\gamma$, such that $\gamma(t_i) = x_i$ are the vertices. (Actually, it is not guaranteed that the above expression converges to $U(t)\psi(x)$ for every $S$, but it does for a large class them.)

Note, that specifically for the kinetic part of $S = \int_0^t (\frac{1}{2} \sum_i m_i \dot x^2_i(t') + V(x(t') ) \, \mathrm{d}t'$ we have:
$$
\int_0^t \dot{\gamma}(t_1, ... t_N) = \sum_{k=0}^N \big| x_{k+1} - x_k \big|^2
$$

From this definition, it is unclear whether $\mathcal{D} x$ is actually a measure, or not, so let us compare the integral to the Wiener integral – an integral over Wiener processes with deviation $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$, which actually does have a proper measure, $w_\sigma$. Let a functional $F[x]$ on Wiener processes depend only on a finite number of points of $x$. Such a functional is called *cylindrical* and is similar in spirit to our action $S(x_1,...x_N)$ on a polygonal line. Then we get:
\begin{align}
  &\int F[x] \, \mathrm{d}w_\sigma\\
  &= \prod_{k=0}^{N-1} \Big( \frac{N}{2\pi \mathrm{i} \, t} \Big)^{\!-N/2} \!\! \int_{\mathbb{R}^{nN}} \hspace{-1em} \exp\big( \frac{-1}{2\sigma} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \big| x_{k+1} - x_k \big|^2 \, \frac{t}{N} \big) \, F(x_1, ... x_{N-1}) \, \mathrm{d}x_1 \, ... \, \mathrm{d}x_{N-1}
\end{align}
One can check that by formally choosing $m_1=...=m_M=\mathrm{i}/\sigma$, we arrive at the definition of the path integral. However, the Wiener measure $w_\sigma$ is only defined for real $\sigma$ – the question is then, can it be generalized?

Surprisingly, the answer is negative. Citing the Cameron's theorem (again from the book of Blank, Exner, Havlíček):

> Let $\sigma$ be a nonzero complex number,  $\operatorname{Re} \sigma \ge 0$. Afinite complex measure $w_\sigma$ such that the relation above holds for any Borel function $F$ from Wiener processes to $\mathbb{C}$, which is cylindrical and bounded, exists **iff** $\sigma \in (0,\infty)$.

This result is taken as a proof that **there isn't a suitable measure for the Feynman path integral**. Instead, we can choose one of several different approaches. Apart from using the definition we used, one can also calculate the Wiener integral, parametrized by $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$, and then make an analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$. Another possible approach is to use generalized Fresnel integrals.